# Parse error sub queries

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, parse-error

I'm trying to show all the games related to the category of the current game played. But I'm getting a parse error in "`if (!empty($_GET['gameId'])) $varGameId  = $_GET['gameId'];`"

**How can I solve this?**

Thank you

```
<?php
$varCategoria_GameData = "0";
$varGameId = 0
if (!empty($_GET['gameId'])) $varGameId  = $_GET['gameId'];
if (isset($_GET["cat"])) {
 $varCategoria_GameData = $_GET["cat"];
}

$sql_categoria = "SELECT * FROM jogos WHERE intCategoria =
( SELECT intCategoria FROM jogos WHERE idGames = $varGameId )";
$query_categoria = mysql_query($sql_categoria, $gameconnection) or die(mysql_error()); 
$categoria = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_categoria);

?>
```

Comment: Add semicolon (`;`) after `$varGameId = 0`.

Comment: **NOTE:** Your code is vulnurable to [***SQL-Injection***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Find prevent measures [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here, semi-colon missing:

```
$varGameId = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss semi colon here: `$varGameId = 0`